# Access 2010 requests parameter value during report assembly

Tags: report, ms-access-2010, optional-parameters, subreport

I know this is a common problem with various queries and I have been through this report several hundred times trying to fix it.  When I attempt to preview the report titled, "RTK Report", I am prompted by Access for a value for "Inventory2013", the table containing the primary data for the report.  This only happens, however, 1.) When I include a subreport titled, "Product Components Subreport" and 2.) Only after I've established the linking field, "ProductID", between the main report and the subreport.  Link to sample database [HERE](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwmwACyyp_xFRGxnaGNta29JM2M/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having appears to be cause by the fact you are linking a subform to your detail section with an ambiguous name of "ProductID". I got it to work by doing the following:

1. In the RecordSource for the main form, I changed the query SQL for column PropertyId to be "SELECT Inventory2013.PRODUCTID AS MainID,"
2. Since this will break the MASTER and CHILD links, I then modified the MASTER to be "MainID" and the CHILD to be "Product_ID"

After that change, the report runs and does not prompt you.

Comment: Outstanding.  Thank you for your time.